# Can not access map

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I get this error when I execute code ,I want to access **server_queue playing**

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'playing')`

This is my code:

```
const server_queue = queue.get(interaction.guild.id);
        if (!server_queue) {
            const server_data = {
                queue: [],
                connection: null,
                dispatcher: null,
                playing: false,
            }
            queue.set(interaction.guild.id, server_data);
            server_data.queue.push(url);
        }
        if (server_queue.playing) {
            return interaction.reply("")
        }
```

Comment: it's because ` queue.get(interaction.guild.id)` returns undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After skipping your first `if` block when `server_queue` doesn't exist, you are then trying to access `playing` on top of the nonexistent `server_queue`. Try adding and `else if` block instead of `if` to ensure you have it.

```
const server_queue = queue.get(interaction.guild.id);
        if (!server_queue) {
            const server_data = {
                queue: [],
                connection: null,
                dispatcher: null,
                playing: false,
            }
            queue.set(interaction.guild.id, server_data);
            server_data.queue.push(url);
        }
        else if (server_queue.playing) {
            return interaction.reply("")
        }
```